# R generating decile

Tags: r

I'm trying to generating decile by revising the the following code

```
df$quantile <- with(df, factor(
                        findInterval(test, c(-Inf,
                           quantile(test, probs=c(0.25, .5, .75)), Inf)), 
                        labels=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
  ))
```

For decile:

```
df$decile <- with(df, factor(
                            findInterval(test, c(-Inf,
                               probs=c((0:9)/10), Inf)), 
                            labels=c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4","Q5","Q6","Q7","Q8","Q9","Q10")
      ))
```

What I do not understand is why do I need to create 10 labels for decile when I only have to create 4 for quantile?

Thank you!

Comment: Because in one case you split into 4 groups while the other you split into 10 groups? Take a look at the `findInterval` results separately from the `factor` code, and you will see one has 4 unique values, the other 10.

Comment: Your code is actually incorrect: you need `(1:9)/10`, not 0. Currently you are generating a vector 12-long and it needs to be 11-long.